# KendoUI grid cell remove Comma Group Seperator

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

We've got a text grid cell in a KendoUI grid which has a format of "{0:n0}". The problem I have is that when you type in a large number of say "123456" that gets formatted to "123,456".

Just wondering what I need to change to remove the comma from the outputted text?

Answer (score 1):

The "n" means number format, which adds commas.

The second zero means 0 decimal places.

So if you want no decimal places and no commas, I believe you need `{0:0}`

Source: 
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/globalization/numberformatting